# Why is my PHP code not properly query-ing the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The problem lies in the perform query lines of code. I'm trying to insert those two strings into that column in my database. I'm not getting an error, but it's not working. Furthermore, if I change "Checked Boxes" which is the column name to some random string, I don't get an error, which suggests that the code is not connecting to my database properly? My end goal is to put the values of $_POST["nutrient"] into a column in my database. Thanks.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){  
print_r ($_POST["nutrient"]);
}


session_start();

//establish connection
$server = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$database = "gainlife_cavin";
$table = "cavintable"; 

//connect PHP script to database
$connection = mysqli_connect("$server","$db_username","$db_password","$database");

    //check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    //perform query
mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM $table");
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO $table(Checked Boxes) VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire')")




    //mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Check other mysql errors

Comment: Your query specifies 2 columns of data. But you have "Checked boxes" as a column name. Either as @Olaf Dietsche says that is 2 columns and you need a comma between them, or that is just one column name (in which case you need back ticks around the name when it contains spaces) and you need to specify the other column name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't check any return codes. Without this, you cannot be sure if there is an error or not.

The reason for the failing insert might be a missing comma between the column names. When you change the insert statement to

```
INSERT INTO $table(Checked, Boxes) VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire')
```

it should work, provided the column names are correct, of course.